# ¿como puedo poner tiempo en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

el dia de hoy me encuentro desarrollando un programa básico donde necesito un tiempo de espera menor a 1 segundo ya estuve investigando antes de preguntas y no encontré una solución lo unico que encontre fue la libreria TIME la cual su tiempo de respuentas en de 1 segundo

```
ejecutar
tiempo menos de un segundo
ejecutar
```

muchas gracias

Comment: Hola ¿A qué te refieres con "poner tiempo" y con "tiempo de respuesta" exactamente? ¿Te refieres a un tiempo de espera, es decir a `time.sleep`? Aún así la resolución de `sleep` no es de un segundo, es generalmente de milisegundos, aunque depende del sistema operativo, puedes pasar floats sinproblema, `time.sleep(0.5)` (medio segundo).

Comment: uso windows 10 me refiero a tiempo de espera para ejecutar o realizar la siguiente linea de codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función que buscas se llama sleep y es del modulo time:

```
import time 

print("Hello World")

time.sleep(0.01)

print("Bye World")
```